# C++ / priority_queue / Expression: invalid comparator

Tags: c++, stl

**EDIT**
I included a screenshot of the compile error with reworked code. [compile error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72XTT.png)

**ORIGINAL POST**
I am writing a little program to practice my knowledge of priority_queue containers. I am trying to create a priority-queue that takes in Person objects that have an age and sex. The queue is supposed to prioritize older ages and then females over males (ie. older females are prioritized over younger females and females are prioritized over males). I've written a predicate that should handle the prioritization but I get a Expression: invalid comparator error when I try to compile the code snippet below. Can anyone explain what the problem is with my predicate?

```
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
public: 
    int age;
    bool isFemale; 

    Person(int Age, bool Female)
    {
        age = Age;
        isFemale = Female; 
    }

    bool operator < (const Person& compareHuman) const
    {
        bool bRet = false;

        if (age < compareHuman.age)
            bRet = true;

        if (isFemale && compareHuman.isFemale)
            bRet = true;

        return bRet;    
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>> humanStack;
    humanStack.push(Person(15, true));
    humanStack.push(Person(42, true));
    humanStack.push(Person(76, true));
    humanStack.push(Person(65, false));
    humanStack.push(Person(21, false));
    humanStack.push(Person(35, true));
    humanStack.push(Person(15, false));

    while(humanStack.size() != 0)
    {
            std::cout << "This person is age " << humanStack.top().age << std::endl;
            humanStack.pop(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Actual error message ?

Comment: It seems fine using [GCC 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/8ajqT4)

Comment: change vector<Person>> humanStack to vector<Person> > humanStack to remove the warning, but your code compiles fine. however your comparision is not quite right, maybe try using a return statement in 1 line?

Comment: I think the error is a runtime error from Visual C++. Its debug builds include code that will detect problems with things that should have a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your less than predicate isn't implemented correctly. As written a value will compare less than itself if `isFemale` is true. A value should never compare less than itself with a valid predicate. You probably want something like this:

```
bool operator < (const Person& compareHuman) const
{
    if (age < compareHuman.age)
        return true;
    else if (compareHuman.age < age)
        return false;

    // Note the ! added on this line
    return isFemale && !compareHuman.isFemale;
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying the predicate to the solution you provided. But I am still given the same error. I edited to original post to show the error message. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SeanBrent I made a mistake and forgot the case where compareHuman.age < age. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles w/o error for me using C++11. (clang).

In c++03, the compiler complains about `vector<Person>> humanStack` - to fix that, insert a space between the two angle brackets thus: `vector<Person> > humanStack`

Comment: Once you fix that, I think you'll find that your comparison predicate is not quite right, as well.

Comment: You are correct, something is still incorrect in the predicate.